# How to get the number of records for a Crystal Reports drill down section?

Tags: crystal-reports, drilldown

I am new to crystal reports and have a question.

I have constructed a report that has sections and each section can be drilled down for details. I would like to add a counter after each section that will tell how many records there will be if the user click it to drill down.

Example: non drilled down "main menu"

```
Report header
-Section1 (number of records in drilled down section one)
-Section2 (number of records in drilled down section two)
```

drilled down section one

```
Section header
-Record1
-Record2
```

How can I construct and add such a counter?

Thanks for the help, Sziro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select a field in the `details` section
- Select Insert | Summary Field...
- Change the operation to `Count`

Comment: Precisely that. Thanks.